# Open an activity inside an alert dialog box in android

Tags: java, android, list

Can I trigger an activity inside an alert box?

Here is what I am trying out:
I have list of items in DB.

I have main.class - which has a button - on click on the button it gets to list.class (This list oncreate gets and all values of db and displays (async is used)) but this is shown in full screen.

Instead I want to show the list of fetched items in a alert dialog instead of showing it in full screen? Is this possible?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: 1st : fetch value from db,                                          2nd : add to an arraylist                                           3rd: use these values in to dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to show your activity in a alert dialog instead of an activity/page.

It's simple if is that what you are looking for.
Just add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in your manifest file for the corresponding activity(list activity). And call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` before `setContentView` in your activity class, your activity will be displayed as an alert dialog.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling another activity just create an alertdialog an do setContentView in that Alert.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertbox.setCancelable(false);
    alertbox.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
            new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog al = alertbox.create();
    LayoutInflater li = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View v = li.inflate(you_layout_resource_id, null);
    al.setContentView(v);
    al.show();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You won't create an activity inside a dialog but you need to build a dialog with the list of your items.
You can use AlertDialog.Builder with setSingleChoiceItems method to set your items.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot. You may use the "handle" to finish this.